# Add softwarerecommendations subdomain, aliased to softwarerecs

Tags: feature-request, subdomains

Currently it just gives an error page saying it doesn't exist. Obviously it resolves to a web server, so better to just serve the Software Recommendations site directly. Even the error page can be improved to provide a link to the correct site instead of incorrectly stating that it doesn't exist.

Comment: The site url for software recommendations is https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. What you are seeing is a default "this subdomain doesn't exist" page/redirect; you'd see exactly the same page for e.g., https://inappropriatecontent.stackexchange.com/ or https://user-chloe.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Do you think the site should be harder to navigate and use, or easier?

Comment: How often do users navigate by _typing an entire URL_ into their location bar, rather than clicking on the link in the Stack Exchange menu (optionally using the search feature) or a bookmark or typing part of the URL with the rest being auto-completed? Is it really worth the effort to implement a list of possible suggestions or synonyms?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304959/could-language-learning-questions-without-their-own-se-site-be-redirected-to-lan

Comment: I should note that the only reason I have not made my first comment into an Answer, and have not encouraged Sonic the Inclusive Hedgehog to do the same with his comment to jkdev's answer is because I believe that those statements need to come from a member of the StackExchange team directly in order to be official. Until they have spoken, it's all just surmise and guesses, no matter how accurate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should Stack Exchanges sites with top-level domains have \*.stackexchange.com redirects?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73434/should-stack-exchanges-sites-with-top-level-domains-have-stackexchange-com-red)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar solution: Redirect the URL.

*softwarerecommendations.stackexchange.com --> softwarerecs.stackexchange.com*

We're already doing this with Software Engineering:

*programmers.stackexchange.com --> softwareengineering.stackexchange.com*

Comment: That redirection is due to the site originally being called Programmers.

Comment: Do note that all current redirects in the system exist due to special circumstances. In this case, the Software Engineering site was previously called Programmers. There are some other cases, such as Psychology being previously called "Cognitive Sciences" and thus having the redirect `cogsci.stackexchange.com`, and Ask Ubuntu previously being called Ubuntu Stack Exchange and thus having the redirect `ubuntu.stackexchange.com`. The SE team has generally refused to have redirects except under these special circumstances.

Comment: This is my favorite answer but not sure I should be the one to select it because I do not have the access to implement it and selecting an answer will mark it closed and the owners will ignore it.

Comment: @Chloe: Accepting an answer does not keep SE staff from looking at or implementing the request. It *may* make it a bit less likely, but I'm dubious. Mostly, though, if it doesn't have a [status-*] tag on it, it's eligible.